# Reduzindo quantidades de linhas em uma consulta

Tags: sql, postgresql

No meu sistema eu tenho 3 tabelas:

-Tabela Filme - um filme possui vários artistas

-Tabela Artista

-Tabela Participa filme - essa tabela, contém os ID's da tabela filme e artista.

ai quando quero selecionar um filme com todos os seus artista faço o seguinte:

```
select ar.*, f.* from filme as f inner join participa_filme as pf on pf.id_filme = f.id_filme inner join artista as ar on ar.id_artista = pf.id_artista
```

Ai ele me retorna, todos os artista do filme titanic

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

minha pergunta é, tem como eu retornar apenas um registro do filme titanic com todos os seus artistas ? sem criar uma linha pra cada artista do filme.

Comment: Você quer criar uma coluna com  todos os artistas, ex: Leonardo, Kate winslet, etc

Comment: isso mesmo @JefersonAlmeida

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está utilizando, a resposta vai ser diferente dependendo do qual vc esteja utilizando?

Comment: eu estou utilizando o Postgresql, pq dessa forma que está, la no meu sistema ele está criando um objeto para cada artista, e eu quero que ele crie apenas um objeto filme de todos os seus artistas. @JefersonAlmeida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No **PostgreSQL 9.0** ou mais recente você pode utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
select f.*, string_agg(ar.nome, ', ') as artistas
from filme as f 
    inner join participa_filme as pf 
        on pf.id_filme = f.id_filme 
    inner join artista as ar 
        on ar.id_artista = pf.id_artista
group by f.id_filme, f.titulo -- Aqui você vai por todos os campos que vc quer agrupar de filme
```

No **PostgreSQL 8.4** ou mais recente você pode utilizar dessa outra maneira:

```
select f.*, array_to_string(array_agg(ar.nome, ', ')) as artistas
from filme as f 
    inner join participa_filme as pf 
        on pf.id_filme = f.id_filme 
    inner join artista as ar 
        on ar.id_artista = pf.id_artista
group by f.id_filme, f.titulo -- Aqui você vai por todos os campos que vc quer agrupar de filme
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, Obrigado !